# Adding Shininess/glossiness to image with opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project where I need to add shiny/glossy texture to image. I have tried some basic operation of OpenCV but no good results were achieved. I have gone through some tutorials on how to detect shiny object but unable to find how to make any object shiny/glossy
All Suggestions/answers are appreciated ...
TIA !

[Before Lips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A68v.jpg)

[After Lips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmXsL.jpg)

Comment: Add some example images and the code you have tried with until now. That way it would be easier for the community to help you.

Comment: @VardanAgarwal edited please check